# Inject Services to Controller on certain browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which uses the `$location` service in angular, however we only need to use it in HTML5 mode, if the browser doesn't support `history.pushstate` we want to omit the service from the controller so it doesn't rewrite the URL to `/#/2016-17` and instead doesn't do any routing. However if you inject `$location` into a controller, it automatically routes using the hashbang method.

Code below for reference:

```
function SearchAdvancedController($location) {
    $location.url("/", false);
}

function config($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: true,
     rewriteLinks: false,
     requireBase: false
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Angular is mainly made for SPA. You want to reload your app every time if the browser doesn't support `history.pushstate` ??

Comment: @SteevePitis I don't want it to do anything, $location isn't a critical feature, all it's being used for is to change URL as a user searches, which isn't a key feature on older browsers

Answer (score 0):

You should always be injecting the service into your controller, unless you want a lot of `if..else` conditions which check whether the service exists or not. The simple thing to do is to define your own service to change URLs, and conditionally have it do nothing:

```
module.service('MyLocation', function ($location) {
    this.url = function () {
        if (/* browser supports pushstate */) {
            $location.url.apply($location, arguments);
        }
    };
});

function SearchAdvancedController(MyLocation) {
    MyLocation.url('/', false);
}
```

You may want to play around with [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) for this purpose too.

Comment: Will this apply on page load too?

Comment: Meaning what exactly?

Comment: Is $location still being injected?

Comment: I just tried this and it is still routing away from the page

Comment: If your controller doesn't ask for it it won't receive it…

Comment: Sounds like a separate problem you're describing.

Comment: $location isn't a critical feature, all it's being used for is to change URL as a user searches (We're not using angular search functionality due to having Django in the back end), which isn't a key feature on older browsers but injecting it into a controller causes it to be routed to /#/whatever compared to just /whatever as the page exists already